# Legend only displaying one letter

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

In a plot of wind resistance versus coefficients of drag, I have the following line defining the legend for the black dashed curve:

```
ax.legend(perpendicular_plate,'Flat Perpendicular Plate')
```

However, the legend is displaying only one letter of the name.  I have used a legend many times, but never the `ax.legend` api...(top right corner)

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly to get this result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to give the label(s) as an iterable of strings (i.e. a list or a tuple), even if there's only one label.

So, this should work:

```
ax.legend([perpendicular_plate],['Flat Perpendicular Plate'])
```

So what's happening in your case is because strings are iterable in python, its iterating on your string, and taking just the first item of the string (`F`), and using that.